# Yesod - Should user profile pictures be stored in the static directory?

Tags: haskell, yesod

Currently profile pictures that the users upload are saved to /static/avatars/{upload-date}. I then generate the StaticR route for the image via information stored in the database (they were added at runtime so the StaticR route doesn't already exist).

The problem I've run into is that when a user updates their profile picture they still get the old one due to the caching of static files. Is there some way around this or should I be storing the images somewhere else? If so then how do I go about accessing the images from say /avatars/{upload-date}/{userid}.png?

I know I could create a route along the lines of /avatars/#Day/#UserId but I'm not sure how I would get the ".png" or ".jpg" appended to that. Or what I would write for the handler function.

Comment: What's the code that's doing the filesaving so far? I think having a look at that might be helpful.

Comment: @AJFarmar the file saving is spread across a few functions, is there a specific part that you would like to see / think would be useful? I can put all of them up if you want but I thought I would ask first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know I could create a route along the lines of /avatars/#Day/#UserId but I'm not sure how I would get the ".png" or ".jpg" appended to th

There is no need that your url should end up with a `png` or `jpeg` extension. All you need to make sure is that your content type header is set properly.

> Or what I would write for the handler function.

That's quite simple. If you are serving `png` images, then all you have to do is use the functions [sendFile](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.0/yesod-core-1.4.35.1/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v:sendFile) and [typePng](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.4/yesod-core-1.4.36/Yesod-Core-Content.html#v:typePng) to serve them:

```
myAvatarHandler = sendFile typePng "/home/yesod/static/avatars/day/userid.png"
```

Also in your example, make sure to store timestamp of the upload and change your url according to that. Or else two profile images updated in the same day will be cached.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm a bit confused about how to use the handler function e.g. when I want to use it as the source of an image tag. Should I create a new Route for avatars? In your answer you showed the path still being in static, I already had a way of serving the images in static using StaticR but the problem was that they were being cached therefore when a user uploaded a new image it wasn't showing the new one even though the file in the file system was updated, wouldn't your answer have the same problem?

Comment: @JamesBurton As indicated in my answer, I would recommend you to store the timestamp of the image (in the day part). That way, you are guaranteed to get unique urls for picture uploads.

Comment: Ok, is there a reason I should user the handler in your answer instead of generating StaticR routes like I did before?

Comment: @JamesBurton You don't need to use my handlers at all and I would recommend you to not use one since it's already accessible via the `/static` path! That was just a demo example.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll add your suggestion of using the timestamp into my current implementation.